# Creating a class that generates and random number

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, nested-loops

My assignment is to generate a random number from one and ten, the user guesses the number and depending on too high or low, will guess again. When the number is guessed correctly it will display that it took X number of times to guess it. Rather than having someone do it all for me, id like an explanation so I can help myself in the future. I hope I have shown what needs to still be done below. Thanks.

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessTheNumber {
    private SecureRandom randomNumber = new SecureRandom();
    private Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    private int numberOfGuesses;

    public void play() {
        int theNumber = 1 + randomNumber.nextInt(10);
        numberOfGuesses = 0;

        int guess = askForGuess();

        //see if their guess is correct, I know a Boolean is needed somewhere here. 
        //otherwise call askForGuess() again, also If and While statements. 

            System.out.printf("You guessed correctly in %d times%n", numberOfGuesses);
    }

    private int askForGuess() {
        numberOfGuesses++;
        int guess = 0;

        //ask for the guess
        //make sure the guess is valid

        return guess;
    }
}

import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessTheNumberTest {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        GuessTheNumber game = new GuessTheNumber();
        int playAgain;

        do {
            game.play();
            System.out.println("Play again? 1-yes, 0-no");
            playAgain = scanner.nextInt();
        } while(playAgain == 1);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try accepting inputs from the user till the userinput matches the randomly generated number. Also keep incrementing the count of numberOfGuesses. When the user input matches the random number, return the number of guesses and print it.
You are probably looking for something like :

```
private int askForGuess(int theNumber) {

        int guessed = in.nextInt();
        numberOfGuesses = 1;
        while(guessed != thetheNumber )
        {
            guessed = in.nextInt();
            numberOfGuesses++;
        }
       return numberOfGuesses;
    }
```

Note: You might want to make your theNumber variable global or pass ti along to your askForGuess() function

Comment: Thanks a lot. Ill give it a try.